# pdfbox Load - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset --PDDocument.load()

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, pdfbox

I am trying to merge multiple pdf files using pdfbox utility, below code works fine when i have less number of files.
While doing merge for 3000+ files i am getting

> connection reset exception at
> source = PDDocument.load(is);

Tried debugging but no much luck

```
    for(allinputfiles)
    {    AmazonS3URI s3URI = new AmazonS3URI(fileToBeDownloaded);
        S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(s3URI.getBucket(), s3URI.getKey());
        S3ObjectInputStream s3InputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
MyS3ObjectStream.add(s3InputStream );
return MyS3ObjectStream;
    }


                    



 PDDocument destination = new PDDocument();
    PDDocument source;
for (MyS3ObjectStream s3fileobj : MyS3ObjectStream) {
                
                
                PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
                pdfMerger.setDestinationFileName(MergedFile.pdf);
                
                try (InputStream is = s3fileobj.getS3ObjectInputStream())
                {
                      source = PDDocument.load(is);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LOG.error("Error in Loading PDF file for conversion");
                    continue;
                }
                
                try
                {
                    pdfMerger.appendDocument(destination, source);
                    destination.save(MergedFile.pdf);
                
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {   LOG.error("Error in PDF Append method , response added to failed file.");
                    
                    continue;
                    
                }
                finally
                {
                         source.close();
                   
                }
            }
```

Aim is to merge 3000+ documents using pdfbox.

Exception

```
Error in Loading PDF file for conversion
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readFully(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:461)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:243)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1508)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1479)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
    at java.base/java.security.DigestInputStream.read(DigestInputStream.java:162)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.DigestValidationInputStream.read(DigestValidationInputStream.java:59)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream.read(S3AbortableInputStream.java:125)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFile.createBuffer(ScratchFile.java:443)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1228)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1130)
```

Comment: Consider downloading the PDF to a local file or byte array and opening it from there.

Comment: I don't know s3, but appararently this is known problem. Coincidentally there's a Tika issue that deals with a similar problem and allows retries: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3831

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am getting this issue when loading input stream object ( pdf files <List> retrieved  from S3 )

Comment: If you take a look at the stack trace, you can see that the issue occurs while reading from the stream. Thus, it may actually be a connection issue, or an issue in the Java network io code, or possibly an effect of some lock up of your jre (e.g. due to garbage collection in a very constrained memory situation). I'd propose catching that exception and retrying as already mentioned by @Tilman.

Comment: The code is not very clear. Why are you creating a `PDFMergerUtility` inside the loop?

Comment: You should just download all files and create a single `PDFMergerUtility` to merge them all.

Comment: @Olivier Requirement is to capture any failed pdf while merge

Comment: Can you show how you create MyS3ObjectStream?

Comment: @pringi MyS3ObjectStream is List of input stream content from S3 ... above code works fine for limited docs but fails/ connection reset when number of input files grows

Comment: *"MyS3ObjectStream is List of input stream content from S3"* - if you're having very many streams in that list, chances are that the underlying connections time out before your code gets around to read the streams. This looks like an error-prone architecture.

Comment: I guess the problems is that you are opening multiple input streams for AWS, and only later you use them. In that period, connection is closed due not being used (probably by AWS). The solution is to have only on for cycle where you fetch the input stream and use it. You merge operation takes some time, and the size of the files also increases the time. More file will take longer time, and the "original connection" opened in the first for cycle will be closed. Best to either open and process and merge each file or download them all and then process each one.

Answer (score 0):

your try catch finally logic is broken. you're only "finally" closing stuff in the second `try{/**/}catch` routine.

Comment: Yes , reason I am doing append in second try catch and if i close source/ destination early i will not be able to append to file